# d3js stacked bar chart with groups

Tags: d3.js

I'm new to learning d3 and so any advice on improving any inefficiencies in my charts would be greatly appreciated. I am using d3js to produce a horizontal stacked bar chart with two color scales.

In this example, there are two teams and a total of 8 players. We are charting the players first based on total points, then points per game. Then, I am also using two different color scales to show which team they belong to.

I did this using this stack bar example as reference: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886208

... but in order to color each player (the y axis) using the color scale associated with the team, I had to first remove the fill that was being applied to each of the wrapping groups made for each game. Then I had to add the key for each stack() series to each data array in that series.

When drawing the individual s I had to do an if and hard code the if condition that tells it which color scale to use in which case.

Here is my block: https://bl.ocks.org/Ognami/2128772d2d7c1d2708d973b9401e8e1f

My question, most importantly, is there an easier way to pass this key along to all of the data arrays in each series? And is there a way around the conditionals for choosing which scale?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some small optimizations.  Store the color scales in a object:

```
var z = {
  'a': d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .range(["#8cb6d9", "#4787ba", "#216297"]),
  'b': d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .range(["#ff5555", "#ff1122", "#990022"])
};
```

Assign there domains as:

```
for (key in z){
 z[key].domain(key);
}
```

Just pass the data down to subselection and get the "key" from the parent:

```
g.append("g")
  .selectAll("g")
  .data(d3.stack().keys(keys)(data))
  .enter().append("g")
  .selectAll("rect")
  .data(d => d)
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
    var key = d3.select(this.parentNode).datum().key;
    return z[d.data.team](key);
  });
```

Now as the number of teams increases or decreases, you only need to edit the `z` to include the the colors for that team.

Full code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ldnm69rBvxoAArYY0nJp?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks! I updated the block with your suggestions, though I couldn't get the object.values() bit to work, I think it has some trouble with it being an object rather than array, or something. But strangely, it doesn't seem to need the domain set at all? I left out that section and it seems to get along just fine...?

Comment: @Ognami, `Object` with a capital `O`?  What error does it throw?

Comment: Yes, it says `Uncaught TypeError: Object.values is not a function`

Comment: @Ognami, my bad, didn't realize that wasn't well supported across browsers.  See updated answer.